# Ng-grid vs. ui-grid

Tags: ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I looked at the angular-ui modules because I need to implement a grid.

I saw that there is the stable ng-grid and the unstable version ui-grid.

Which version should I use? 
Are they very different or hard to switch?

Comment: So which one did you choose ? How did it go ?

Comment: I'm curious as well which one you chose. If one went with ui-grid, would one be able to easily use most of the same code with ng-grid, if ui-grid did break?

Comment: I didn't need the grid after all. Sorry guys :)

Answer (score 26):

The github repo says that all development will happen on ui-grid (ng-grid 3). That means ng-grid has become a legacy grid. ui-grid is stable enough to use in my opinion and the only reason to use ng-grid is if you already started with it. New projects would be better off using ui-grid. They also claim that the performance of ui-grid is better than that of ng-grid though I haven't tested that.

UPDATE:

A stable version of UI Grid 3 is out which means that it can be used in production applications. On their documentation site, they have a guide on how to upgrade from legacy ng-grid. See [Tutorial: 099 Upgrading](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2)

Comment: I am building a new web app from scratch and tried ng-grid and ui-grid in the beginning. Some of my grids had 1000-2000 rows and I can say that ui-grid was MUCH faster than ng-grid for this. From memory, ng-grid was displaying in about 60 seconds, and for ui-grid, it was around 1 second. So, I would agree with the ui-grid performance claims you mentioned.

Comment: We used ng-grid 2.x in production 3.x (ui-grid) - is probably 2-3x faster than the previous (and is now in general availability release)

Answer (score 11):

It's the same project. ng-grid is older (version 2.x), UI Grid is newer (version 3.x) but not officially relased yet (currently in [release candidate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2545) status). They're very similar, compare the tutorials for [v2 (ng-grid)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) and [v3 (UI Grid)](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial).

Edit (Nov 12 2014):
One major feature from v2 that is still missing in v3 is grouping ([github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/935)). If that's something you can't do without stick with v2 for now.

Comment: Just a note: an evaluation grouping feature has been added to the 3.x codebase

Answer (score 6):

ui-grid is replacing ng-grid, and support for ng-grid is getting thin as most of the original (2.x) contributors are no longer active, the remaining contributors are almost exclusively working on 3.0 only.

So, I would use ng-grid if:

- you are already using it and don't have any pressing issues that would force an upgrade
- you really need a stable and well tested product

I would use ui-grid if:

- you are starting a new project now, and not intending to be in production for a few months
- you need a feature that ui-grid offers and ng-grid doesn't (such as exporting, importing, state saving), or specific functions that ui-grid offers
- you plan on extensively customising or pushing the limits of the functionality - ui-grid is more customisable and more supportable
- you have tried it and it does everything you want
- you don't need IE support earlier than IE9 (and mostly IE10 and up only)

In general, I'd lean towards ui-grid unless you can't use it for some reason.

Note also that grouping was recently released in alpha.

EDIT: We've also recently noticed that Amazon Web Services are using ui-grid in their console in a couple of places....so I guess that partly answers the question as to whether it's ready for production usage.

Comment: do you know whats the equivalent for ng-grid `beforeSelectionChange` in ui-grid ?