# What are the difference between ng-grid and ui-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

### What are the difference between ng-grid and ui-grid in angularjs

I need some more details about those

- What are the features?
- Which one is better for re-usability
- Performance details about if we have large list of data?
- And which one is support for customization ( We need edit and delete and filtering,etc...)?

Comment: You can look ar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212094/ng-grid-vs-ui-grid

Comment: Yes i already saw it... But  there have only few explanation. I want little more explanation.

Comment: Have you found out yet or are you still waiting or do you not care anymore?

Comment: Still waiting,  but no one response for my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: ui-grid is a (non-backward compatible) updated version of ng-grid. Ng-grid is now no longer under development and is a legacy product - **use ui-grid**

Long answer to address each of your bullets:

1+4) If you want to know about the features and customization options for the ui-grid you can easily read up on them :) Take advantage of the great documentation on their [page](http://ui-grid.info/) - read the API and tutorial to learn all about the basic features and customizations available.

2) There are answers already answers to a very similar (duplicate!?)  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212094/ng-grid-vs-ui-grid) as @squiroid mentioned above. However the answers are a bit out of date as there is now a stable version of ui-grid available meaning ng-grid is at this point *officially a legacy product* -use UI-grid

3) The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212094/ng-grid-vs-ui-grid) also mention - and I have seen from personal experience that UI-Grid has MUCH better performance for large data sets.