# Difference between ngGrid and uiGrid?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am starting to work on my grid implementation using AngularJS ngGrid...But I see the next version as UI grid...which is unstable? Have any one ever used any of them and what is the main difference of both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ng-grid vs. ui-grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212094/ng-grid-vs-ui-grid)

Answer (score 0):

> The github repo says that all development will happen on ui-grid
>   (ng-grid 3). That means ng-grid has become a legacy grid. ui-grid is
>   stable enough to use in my opinion and the only reason to use ng-grid
>   is if you already started with it. New projects would probably be
>   better off using ui-grid. They also claim that the performance of
>   ui-grid is better than that of ng-grid though I haven't tested that.
>
> It's the same project. ng-grid is older (version 2.x), UI Grid is
>   newer (version 3.x) but not officially relased yet (currently in
>   [release candidate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2545) status). They're very similar, compare the
>   tutorials for [v2 (ng-grid)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) and [v3 (UI Grid)](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial).
>
> Edit (Nov 12 2014): One major feature from v2 that is still missing in
>   v3 is grouping ([github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/935)). If that's something you can't do
>   without stick with v2 for now.

Answer (score 0):

I started using the ui-grid in my project. It is pretty stable if you choose the stable version download but if you wanted to keep upto date with the new features, you can start using the unstable version (with possible bugs).

The performance has been pretty good so far with ui-grid. I load a lot of data based on the user action, including adding/removing columns on demand. The performance is good so far.

Also the code structure is way better in the ui-grid where main features are separated as modules with directives which helps a lot. For example if you want to use pagination you can include ui-grid-pagination directive and ui.grid.pagination module.

Comment: I am having a display error while integrating UI grid...plz have a look at my recent question and let me know if u can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924891/ui-grid-css-not-working

Comment: Provided an answer there.