# UI Grid CSS not working

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I tried to create a grid using UI grid (Recent version of ngGrid) which is unstable version and integrated in my current project.

It is Not correctly displaying the (icon angle down and row selected icon) as needed While including the CSS file in project (by downloading the file and uploading) its giving me display errors as shown below.

But, if i directly give the web url for CSS file in my project...it is displaying correctly.

```
//web url: 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">

//my url
<link href="~/Scripts/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't want to depend on web URL to display...is there any solution that I can implement on my side.

Please refer the image for before and after using web link.

link for Images: http://postimg.org/image/omhlfs8nd/

The top one is how it's supposed to and the bottom one explains my display error.

ThankQ for your time.

Comment: Did you try removing the `~` char from the url?

Comment: I don't think that will help coz ~ represents the root path

Comment: Not really, if you want to represent the root path just say href="/Scripts/ui-grid-unstable.css"

Comment: Yea actually I tried removing ~ and It's giving me 404. But when I place it back, it works fine.

Comment: Can you share the plnkr url, if you are trying this in plnkr.

Comment: Sure. Here is the plnkr               http://plnkr.co/edit/zIbXsN0IcU7As6DMjjy9?p=preview

Comment: In plnkr its displaying correctly though...I am getting error on my localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple error. Make sure you have the ttf,woff and svg files from the ui-grid download in your css folder. From you code, you should have it under ~/Scripts/ folder.

Comment: Thank u...as I created this grid in plunkr I guess i don't need the font files then...but when I install it in my proj I should include these files. Is that rite?

Comment: yes. If you dont keep the files in your local server you need to have them.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to previous comments to download tff, svg and woff files:
You need to download ui-grid.eot as well to get it perfect.